# how many request and response pair of object will be created by container for 4 concurrent request at the same time?

Tags: servlets

Suppose 4 requests are made to servlet class at the same time with different request parameters. In this case how many request, response pair of object will be created by container? since each request having different parameter so if container will pass same request and response pair object to each request then each request will get different output??

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter if the request parameters are the same or different - every request is in a thread and has a private HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse.  In your example there would be 4 of each.